# How to pass data from database popup list to javascript interface android and add this value on html webview

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, webview

popupdialog.java

```
public void showCustomRegionPopup() {
.
.
.
            listRegion.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final String region = (String) listRegion.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SQLiteDatabase database = context.pdfDatabaseManager.getReadableDatabase();
                final Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * From " + PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_REGION_TABLE + " WHERE "+ PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_REGION +"='"+region+"'", null);
                String code = "";
                while (c.moveToNext()) code = c.getString(1);
                c.close();
                context.setCodeAndRegion(code,region);
                a.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

androidaction.java

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showCustomRegionPopup(){
        context.popupDialog.showCustomRegionPopup();
}
```

**I want to take database region value from popupdialog.java and pass data to androidaction.java and run this code to put them on html...**

```
webview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:showCustomRegionPopup('".concat(region).concat("');"), null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: check this to learn how to define javascript interface https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Comment: @EliasFazel my question is how i pass data, I read this link but not help me for now...